# Where can I get the offline installer for Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, installer

I just installed Windows 8 Release Preview on my main system and wanted to learn to develop Metro Apps.

I tried the download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads) but all I get is a 1 MB file which wants to download stuff over the internet. Since bandwidth is at a premium, I want to download the ISO once and then all my friends and I can use that.

Does anyone know where I can find the ISO?

Comment: There's a list at the bottom of [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx). A faster way is to use your browser's search for `offline`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> #### All The Download Links - including OFFLINE installers inside ISOs
>
> - Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC
>
>   - [Web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810263)
>   - [ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247147)
> - Visual Studio 2012 Premium RC
>
>   - [Web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247147)
>   - [ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247144)
> - Visual Studio 2012 Professional RC
>
>   - [Web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810223)
>   - [ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247141)
> - Visual Studio 2012 Express RC for Windows 8
>
>   - [Web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810150)
>   - [ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810160)
> - Visual Studio 2012 Test Professional RC
>
>   - [Web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810304)
>   - [ISO Image](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247152)

[Source](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find the ISO image, you can instead try to setup your dev environment in a virtual machine (with e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)), and then copy the image to your friends. This way, they don't even need to install Windows 8 themselves.